# CDN not adding methods/properties to window object when trying to use iFrameResizer

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cdn

I am trying to use the [iFrameResizer package](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) on a parent site and embed a basic react page via an iframe. To the parents site's `index.html` I've added the following code:

```js
<iframe frameborder="0" id="sizetracker" src="http://localhost:3001" width="100%"
    style="position: fixed; z-index: 1000; bottom: 0; right: 0"></iframe>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@4.2.11/index.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.iFrameResize({ log: true }, '#sizetracker') // error thrown here
</script>
```

I'm using a cdn to add the package. I've tried the CDN from unpkg (via https://unpkg.com/iframe-resizer@4.3.2/index.js) as well as the url in the `src` attribute above that I got from [js-delivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/iframe-resizer?version=4.2.11).

Two errors are thrown:

1. `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` - this seems to be coming from the CDN's index.js
2. `Uncaught TypeError: window.iFrameResize is not a function` - I'm guessing this is because of the above failed error.

How can I correctly import via CDN and then use that npm package in `script` tags in my html?

Answer (score 0):

CDN Link was pointing to the wrong JS file. Don't use the one from jsdelivr or direct from unpkg. Instead use: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@4.2.11/js/iframeResizer.min.js